# How do I solve "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0"

Tags: numerical-integration

I need some help solving these, I am new to Mathematica and cannot find the problem.

My equations are as follows-

```
eqn1 = th1''[t] + sin[th1[t]] + 0.01 ((th1[t])^2/(6 *0.025) - 1) th1'[t] -  0.011* cos[th1[t]]*(th1''[t]*cos[th1[t]] - (th1'[t])^2*sin[th1[t]] +th2''[t]*cos[th2[t]] - (th2'[t])^2*sin[th2[t]])

eqn2 = th2''[t] + sin[th2[t]] +0.01 ((th2[t])^2/(6 *0.025) - 1) th2'[t] -0.011* cos[th2[t]]*(th1''[t]*cos[th2[t]] - (th1'[t])^2*sin[th1[t]] + 
 th2''[t]*cos[th2[t]] - (th2'[t])^2*sin[th2[t]])


NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, th1[0] == Pi/4, th2[0] == Pi/4,th1'[0] == 0, th2'[0] == 0}, {th1, th2}, {t, 0, 45}]

NDSolve::ndnum: *Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0*.`.
```

Comment: Hi Abhiroop Bhadra and welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2):

The Wolfram Language in *Mathematica* is [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). So you need to use [`Sin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) and [`Cos`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos.html) instead of `sin` and `cos`

```
eqn1 = th1''[t] + Sin[th1[t]] + 
   0.01 ((th1[t])^2/(6*0.025) - 1) th1'[t] - 
   0.011*Cos[
     th1[t]]*(th1''[t]*Cos[th1[t]] - (th1'[t])^2*Sin[th1[t]] + 
      th2''[t]*Cos[th2[t]] - (th2'[t])^2*Sin[th2[t]]);

eqn2 = th2''[t] + Sin[th2[t]] + 
   0.01 ((th2[t])^2/(6*0.025) - 1) th2'[t] - 
   0.011*Cos[
     th2[t]]*(th1''[t]*Cos[th2[t]] - (th1'[t])^2*Sin[th1[t]] + 
      th2''[t]*Cos[th2[t]] - (th2'[t])^2*Sin[th2[t]]);

{{th1if, th2if}} = ({th1, th2} /.
   NDSolve[
    {
     eqn1 == 0
     , eqn2 == 0
     , th1[0] == Pi/4
     , th2[0] == Pi/4
     , th1'[0] == 0
     , th2'[0] == 0
     }
    , {th1, th2}
    , {t, 0, 45}
    ]
  )


Plot[
 {th1if[t], th2if[t]}
 , {t, 0, 45}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]